# Updating column values in if loop overwrites other columns in pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to iterate over columns and update values within each column. This is sample code that demonstrates the problem.

```
import pandas as pd 

a = [
    {'A': 'a', 'B': 'b', 'C': 'c'},
    {'A': 'a', 'B': 'b', 'C': 'c'},
    {'A': 'a', 'B': 'b', 'C': 'c'},
]

df = pd.DataFrame(a)

for i, c in enumerate(df.columns):
    print(c, i)
    df[df[c] == 'a'] = i

df
```

The output ends up like this:

```
A 0
B 1
C 2

   A  B  C
0  0  0  0
1  0  0  0
2  0  0  0
```

What is should look like is this:

```
   A  B  C
0  0  b  c
1  0  b  c
2  0  b  c
```

The first pass of the loop changes all columns.

Comment: what you need here , why we do for loop for column assign?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select column for set values in [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html), else are replaced all columns:

```
for i, c in enumerate(df.columns):
    print(c, i)
    df.loc[df[c] == 'a', c] = i

print (df)
   A  B  C
0  0  b  c
1  0  b  c
2  0  b  c
```